# Performing long running compute intensive operation on background thread

Tags: python, tornado

I have written a REST API in Python Tornado framework which predicts the answer of a question from a given paragraph.

---

Here is the Python code for the Tornado handler:

```
def post(self):
    """
    This function predicts the response from the pre-trained Allen model
    """    
    try:
        request_payload = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)

        if (request_payload is None):
            return self._return_response(self, { "message": "Invalid request!" }, 400)

        context = request_payload["context"]
        question = request_payload["question"]

        if(context is None or not context):
            return self._return_response(self, { "message": "Context is not provided!" }, 400)

        if(question is None or not question):
            return self._return_response(self, { "message": "Question is not provided!" }, 400)

        # Compute intensive operation which blocks the main thread
        answer_prediction = predictor.predict(passage=str(context), question=str(question))
        best_answer = answer_prediction["best_span_str"] or "Sorry, no answer found for your question!"

        return self._return_response(self, { "answer": best_answer }, 200)

    except KeyError:
        #Return bad request if any of the keys are missing
        return self._return_response(self, { "message": 'Some keys are missing from the request!' }, 400)

    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        return self._return_response(self, { "message": 'Cannot decode request body!' }, 400)

    except Exception as ex:
        return self._return_response(self, { "message": 'Could not complete the request because of some error at the server!', "cause": ex.args[0], "stack_trace": traceback.format_exc(sys.exc_info()) }, 500)
```

---

**The problem is that the line:**

> **answer_prediction = predictor.predict(passage=str(context),
>   question=str(question))**

**Blocks the main thread for incoming requests and waits until that long running operation is completed whilst blocking for other requests and times out the current request sometimes.**

---

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325939/having-problems-running-a-long-blocking-function-in-a-thread-in-tornado) answer detailing a solution with putting the long running operation in queue, but I am not getting it.

Also due to Python's GIL only one thread can run at the same time, which forces me to spawn a separate process to deal with it, since processes are costly, are there any viable solution to my problem and how to deal with this kind of situations.

**Here are my questions:**

- **How to offload safely compute intensive operations to a background
  thread**
- **How to handle timeouts and exceptions gracefully**
- **How to maintain a queue structure for checking if the long running operation has been completed or not.**

Comment: Did you check Task Schedulers as [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: No I didn't but how is it linked ?

Comment: If current task is heavy and you can add to queue and make concurrent operations.

Comment: @adnbsr you can give an example

Comment: see docs, they are more fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the blocking code in a separate thread. Use [`IOLoop.run_in_executor`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor).

Example:

```
from functools import partial

async def post(self):
    ...

    # create a partial object with the keyword arguments
    predict_partial = partial(predictor.predict, passage=str(context), question=str(question))

    answer_prediction = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, predict_partial)

    ...
```

Comment: So the source for [run_in_executor](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/ioloop.html#IOLoop.run_in_executor) says that `max_workers=(cpu_count() * 5)` what does it mean by that ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee That is the maximum number of threads. If you have a dual core cpu, this value would be equal to 10. That means your server will run at most 10 threads to compute `predictor.predict` for 10 separate requests simultaneously. If more requests come in, they will have to wait until a thread is free. Your server will not block even if all the threads are occupied.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should turn this API call to async call and return immediately  to the caller with a token.

The token will use the token later on in order to check (using another API call) if the operation is completed.